# Order user league by percentage change

Tags: feature-request, reputation, reputation-leagues

It would be nice if you could order the user leagues by percentage change, that would somewhat indicate how fast the user is building its reputation. Of course show that value next to the reputation as well. Maybe call the statistic "Velocity".

One other interesting statistics is to see the average points per answer a user got (maybe excluding bounties). That would basically show how good answers a user writes. Maybe call the statistic "Answer quality"... you should be able to normalize the point for the answer quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have considered putting velocity in there, as well as predictions of how long it will take, at your current rate of rep gain, to "catch" others in front of you.

That's not a high priority at the moment though, but I do think it's interesting.

A lot of the inspiration for rep leagues came from:

http://folding.extremeoverclocking.com/team_list.php

.. and you can get a lot of great ideas from there if you click around and see what's going on.

Comment: Those stats are awesome.  It would be cool to incorporate those in stack exchange.

Comment: Nice that it is on the list somewhere :). Is the "Answer quality" also on the list?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the reputation cap this would penalize high rep users.  But maybe that's what you're after: those low rep users we haven't (yet) heard of but nevertheless hit the cap each day like clockwork.

Comment: I wouldn't say penalize, of course the velocity will most likely be lower for high rep users but I don't see that as penalizing high rep users. And the "Answer quality" as I call it just shows the community how good your answers are, which I really think is relevant.